# Show that if $f$ is uniformly continuous on the closure of $B$, then it is uniformly continuous on $B$. Not trivial?

Tags: metric-spaces, continuity, uniform-continuity

I am not asking for a proof, but rather an explanation of what this question is trying to get me to do. The question is:

Let $f$ be a continuous function on a metric space $\left(X, d\right)$ and $B$ be a nonempty set in $X$. Show that if $f$ is uniformly continuous on the closure of $B$, then it is uniformly continuous on $B$.

I don't understand what there is to show. In my book, the definition of the closure of $B$ is the union of $B$ and its accumulation points. Doesn't this mean that $f$ is automatically uniformly continuous on $B$ since it is contained in its closure? What am I missing here?

Comment: Just to confirm, are you sure the question isn't the other way around (uniformly continuous on $B\Rightarrow$ uniformly continuous on $\overline B$)?

Comment: @stewbasic, I am not sure. I just copied it word for word.

Comment: As it's stated, you're not missing anything. It's obvious

Comment: @mathworker21, okay thanks. I just asked my TA, and he said "it's not trivial," so now I am really confused. But thanks again. I think I will email my professor to clarify the question.

Comment: I edited the subject for traceability, and posted a hint why it might not be trivial after all.

Comment: From my experience, TA's are usually stupider than the students.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed trivial.  Given $\epsilon>0$, any $\delta$ that witnesses uniform continuity on $\overline{B}$ will also work for uniform continuity on $B$, since $B\subseteq\overline{B}$.  I'm guessing that this problem was intended to be stated the other way around (given uniform continuity on $B$, prove it on $\overline{B}$).